# web2py new controller invalid functions

Tags: python, web2py

I have the following controllers in my Application with Web2py

1. abook
2. account
3. ajax
4. default
5. factures
6. letters
7. payment

all works perfectly except abook, which was the last create controller so its the newest, i noticed that every new controllers are now created wont work

```
# abook.py:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
### required - do no delete
response.generic_patterns=['*']
import functions as fu
import os, uuid, string, datetime
if auth.user_id:
    session.language = fu.default_language(db,auth)
else:
    session.language = session.preferredLanguage
def user(): return dict(form=auth())
@auth.requires_login()
def setlanguage(language):
    if session.language == None:
        session.language = session.preferredLanguage
        T.force(session.languageIdentifiers[session.language])
        pass
    else:
        session.language = language
        T.force(session.languageIdentifiers[language])
        pass
    pass
### end requires

def index():
    return dict()

...
...
...
```

and for each function i made a view HTML-template

but i get always

```
invalid function (abook/FUNCTION_NAME)
```

Web2py version: `1.99.7`

Comment: Have you changed something in routes.py?

Comment: what do you have in functions module?

Comment: Is this in production? Try restarting the server.

Comment: @rochacbruno no i didn't change anything there. functions module contents a functions which i wrote to use them, i use that module in all other controllers without any problem, i tried to remove that line but its the same

Comment: @Anthony i tried that many times and i tried to delete all .pyc files produced from web2py ... it still not working

Comment: What if you create a whole new app?